# How can I monitor serial port traffic?

Tags: linux, serial-port

Is there any port monitoring tool to watch the packets written on the port? I especially want to check if my program written in Java works so I need some kind of tool to see if my little application is writing the messages to the port. How do I do this?

Comment: Packets aren't written on the port.  Characters are.  It's not like Ethernet at all.

Comment: Similar questions from sibling SE sites: http://stackoverflow.com/q/940374/12892 and http://serverfault.com/q/112957/4276

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found projects called [Linux Serial Sniffer](http://freshmeat.net/projects/linuxserialsniffer/), [jpnevulator](http://jpnevulator.snarl.nl/), and [Moni](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/moni)(Edit: Updated Link). The first two look like they do exactly what you want. The last one calls itself a monitor, but it actually looks like a standard serial communication program.

Comment: thanks for that !! i will give it a try. by the way i solved the issue from my java side. i was missing a \r, so that prevented my message from writing on to the port. thanks for that anyways!!

Comment: The «LInux Serial Sniffer» is buggy, it absolutely takes out incoming data, thus another application which is actually listen to serial see nothing. But, at least, the data that goes outside seems to go without problem.

Comment: From the [jpnevulator FAQ](https://jpnevulator.snarl.nl/src/current/FAQ): "Jpnevulator was never built to sit in between the kernel and your application."

Comment: -1 because of 3 comments: *LInux Serial Sniffer is buggy*, then *Jpnevulator was never built to sit in between kernel and app* and finaly *Moni is dead*... This answer just point to 3 externals links and don't give a real solution. (3 fail on 3 link, left nothing!)

Comment: I think, this could be deleted in favor of [Alex Stragies's answer using `socat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225904/27653) where solution is located ***between*** serial port and application.

Comment: Yes, this answer should be deleted as it has outlived its usefulness and the original author isn't updating it. By the way, I couldn't get `socat` to do what I wanted, but `interceptty` worked great.

Answer (score 51):

[socat](/questions/tagged/socat) is a tool to connect (nearly) everything to (nearly) everything,
and [tee](/questions/tagged/tee) can duplicate streams. 
In your use case you could connect your serial port `/dev/ttyS0`
to a PTY `/tmp/ttyV0`,
then point your application to the PTY,
and have socat `tee` out Input and Output somewhere for you to observe.

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=socat+serial+port+pty+tee+debug) "socat serial port pty tee debug"
will point you to several "standard procedure" examples, one being:

```
socat  /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0  \
    SYSTEM:'tee in.txt | socat - "PTY,link=/tmp/ttyV0,raw,echo=0,waitslave" | tee out.txt'
```

The files `in.txt` and `out.txt` will then contain the captured data.

Updated after comments:

- The `socat` syntax looks confusing at first,
  but in fact, it's just two nested statements.
  A small price to pay to such a powerful, versatile tool.
- If you need to set up your serial port, or send other ioctls,
  do so before calling socat, as socat cannot proxy them.
- The single-purpose-tool `interceptty` from 2006 has slightly simpler syntax, but can only intercept TTYs (while proxying ioctls),
  and is probably not in your package manager. 
  (Most Linux distros [never added it](https://repology.org/project/interceptty/versions) to their repos.)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica What do you need to proxy the ioctl calls for? If it's just changing the baudrate, try `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 19200`. Technically, it should be possible by intercepting the system call using LD_PRELOAD, same as `padsp`.

Comment: @alex-stragies: I like `socat`, but the syntax is just too cumbersome. For this simple problem, I found the `interceptty` solution posted below to be much simpler:  `interceptty /dev/ttyS0` is all you need to create a PTY called /tmp/interceptty that can then be used by any program as a serial port.

Comment: @hackerb9 As of 03/2020, `interceptty` is not in debian package management, not even `testing`, so -for me and some others- not a viable solution for many situations. And the syntax is only cumbersome the first 5-8 times ;)

Comment: Fair enough. I also tend to stick with software that's been vetted by Debian. Interceptty, despite the author disappearing, seems to be well written. A simple `./configure && make && sudo make install` worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

I don't think the serial driver has any tracing functionality that would allow you to watch packets. You can use `strace` to observe all the reads and writes from your application:

```
strace -s9999 -o myapp.strace -eread,write,ioctl ./myapp
```

Comment: can is send packets to the port if nothign is connected ?

Comment: strace will tell you if it tried to send characters to the port, and what the kernel responded with when it tried.   depending on your flow control settings characters may arrive at the disconnected TXD pin or may not.

Comment: Thanks, have a look at my [dynamic strace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542819/27653), based on this answer!

Comment: This works, but is an overkill in the sense that it'll monitor accesses to _all_ files instead of the single `/dev/tty*` we're interested in.

Comment: This got me going in the direction I needed.  I have a hardware widget with a serial interface that I can only find an ancient Windows-32 app to control, and I was looking to monitor all of it's traffic while running under wine to try and reverse-engineer it in hopes of making a new library.  I found that adding the `-P` option limits strace to only my device, and I also needed `-f` to watch the child/fork processes:
`strace -o wine.strace -f -s 9999 -x -P /dev/ttyUSB0 wine start 'c:/Program Files (x86)/mydir/myapp.exe'`

Answer (score 10):

[`interceptty`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/interceptty) does that job:

```
interceptty /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyDUMMY
```

or, with a nice output format and with configuring the backend device, and with line buffering:

```
interceptty -s 'ispeed 19200 ospeed 19200' -l /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyDUMMY | interceptty-nicedump
```

and then connect with your programme to `/dev/ttyDUMMY`.

Comment: @AlexStragies: I have it on my arch linux system. AUR page: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/interceptty, copy of the sources: https://repo.j5lx.eu/archive/interceptty/interceptty-0.6.tar.gz

Comment: I had to download it (using `wget` since clicking on the `.tar.gz` file seemed to corrupt it somehow), install `gcc` and `make`, then run `./configure` and `make install`.  Does exactly what the OP and I want though.

Comment: Your answer is far the best.

Comment: Worked great on Debian GNU/Linux.  Was able to intercept a Windows program (running in Wine) with a simple `ln -s /tmp/interceptty ~/.wine/dosdevices/com5`.  Excellent answer.

Answer (score 7):

## This is the way I finally choose

Thanks to [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12367/27653)!

```
strace -s 9999 -e read -ffp $(sed '/ttyUSB0/s/^.*proc.\([0-9]\+\).fd.*/\1/p;d' <(ls -l /proc/[1-9]*/fd/* 2>/dev/null)) |& perl -e '$|=1;my %qa=(a=>7,b=>10,e=>33,f=>14,n=>12,r=>15,t=>11);sub cnv { my $ch=$_[0];$ch=$qa{$1} if $ch=~/([abefnrt])/;return chr(oct($ch));  };while (<>) { /^read.\d+,\s+"(.*)",\s\d+.*$/ && do { $_=$1;s/\\(\d+|[abefnrt])/cnv($1)/eg;print; };};'
```

Sorry, I will explain...

```
#!/bin/bash

strace -s 9999 -e read -ffp $(
    sed "/tty${1:-USB0}/s/^.*proc.\([0-9]\+\).fd.*/\1/p;d" <(
        ls -l /proc/[1-9]*/fd/* 2>/dev/null
    )
) 2>&1 |
    perl -e '
        $|=1;
        my %qa=(a=>7,b=>10,e=>33,f=>14,n=>12,r=>15,t=>11);
        sub cnv {
            my $ch=$_[0];
            $ch=$qa{$1} if $ch=~/([abefnrt])/;
            return chr(oct($ch));
        };
        while (<>) {
            /^read.\d+,\s+"(.*)",\s\d+.*$/ && do {
                $_=$1;
                s/\\(\d+|[abefnrt])/cnv($1)/eg;
                print;
            };
        };
    '
```

- I use `ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/fd/* | grep ttyUSB0` instead of `lsof ttyUSB0` because I seen them sometime slow.
- So strace will trace current program using `ttyUSB0`
- Syntax: `tty${1:-USB0}` will permit, used as a script or function, to run them with serial device name as argument: `ttySniff USB0` or `ttySniff S0` and so on.
- Perl script will *`unbackslash`* strings logged by `strace -s 9999`.
- You could replace `strace -e read` by `strace -e read,write` or `strace -e write` depending on your need.

**Note:** I run them by using syntax:

```
 script -t ttySniff.log 2>ttySniff.tm -c "./ttySniff.sh USB0"
```

so I could replay the whole operation and trace timing executions.

Comment: There is no security consideration, about what could be comming by *serial port*!

Comment: Awesome, work well, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When I debug interaction of my application with a serial port, I use [moserial](http://library.gnome.org/users/moserial/stable/basic-usage.html.en).

Comment: What're you talking about, in the docs written it's just a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-blahblah 9600
```

works for me.

Comment: This opens the port and assumes control over it, so nothing else can use it. This does not "monitor" or "sniff" the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

`minicom` is missing from the list of tools to monitor serial ports. Use it as for example to listen to arduino device:

`minicom --device /dev/ttyACM0 --baud 9600`

Comment: OP wrote "monitor", but meant "sniffer" ( = is able to read traffic in transit), while minicom is a serial port "client", and as such is not an answer to this question. The [answer below from mike](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79611/127903) made the same mistake, and the comment there explains the terminology problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ttyUSBSpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ttyusbspy/).
It is on alpha stage, but it works.

Comment: It doesn't. It is written in python, and the code does import some `import pcopy`, which is even Google gave up to find.

Comment: Software/Homepage looks abandoned. Is not in package managers.

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers and approaches to this that each have different properties. A common one is using socat, like the answer Alex gave above that's also discussed [in this blog post](https://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/02/debugginng-serial-interfaces.html).

However, if you'd prefer creating a separate device that's just a read-only version of the original device like myself - say, so that you can open minicom on the read-only device and let other software interact with the read-write device normally - I just came up with the following that works nicely.

```
socat /dev/ttyUSB0,rawer SYSTEM:'tee >(socat - "PTY,link=/tmp/foobar-ro,rawer" >%-) | socat - "PTY,link=/tmp/foobar-rw,rawer,wait-slave"'
```

That's complicated, so I'll break it down a bit. Logically it's this:

```
socat /dev/ttyUSB3,rawer SYSTEM:'tee [READ-ONLY PTY] | [READ-WRITE PTY]'
```

And it works roughly like so:

1. The first socat command sets up a bidirectional pipe between the first address (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) and second (the `SYSTEM` command).
2. Inside the `SYSTEM` command now, tee duplicates its stdin (i.e. the output of `/dev/ttyUSB0`) to both `[READ-ONLY PTY]` and to its own stdout, which we then pipe to `[READ-WRITE PTY]`.
3. `[READ-ONLY PTY]` is created with a 2nd socat command where the first address is `-` (shorthand for socat's `STDIO` address type) and the second is a new PTY. We also make sure to close this 2nd socat command's stdout with `>%-`; this is what makes it read-only.

   - For a reason I don't quite understand, unless the 2nd socat's stdout is closed, tee seems to include the output from the process substitution in its own output. I'm not sure why tee would be reading from its arguments at all.
4. Finally, `[READ-WRITE PTY]` is created with a 3rd socat command similar to the 2nd. This 3rd socat's stdout becomes the output of the SYSTEM address in the 1st socat and is fed to the original device's input, completing the loop.