# Serial device data feedback loop possible?

Tags: terminal, serial-port

Is it possible to do some echo on `/dev/ttyS8` serial device in one terminal window, and in second to cat `/dev/ttyS8` and display data from that file?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor a serial port? There are a lot of techniques to do it. E.g. [How can I monitor data on a serial port in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940374/how-can-i-monitor-data-on-a-serial-port-in-linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you stick a serial loopback adapter in the specified serial port: Yes.

<kbd>[image: Serial Loopback Adapter]

 Pinout:

 * Receive and transmit (2 & 3)

 * Request to send and Clear to send (7 & 8)

 * Data carrier detect, Data set ready and Data terminal ready (1, 6 & 4)</kbd>

If you want to debug an application talking through a serial port, you could use this [socat](/questions/tagged/socat) command:

```
socat /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 SYSTEM:'tee input.txt | socat - "PTY,link=/tmp/ttyV0,raw,echo=0,waitslave" | tee output.txt'
```

(From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225904/127903)

Comment: So if I echo something to /dev/ttyS8 it goes out to UART port, and I cannot see it with cat, only with loopback adapter?

Comment: You need the loopback adapter. Serial transmit and receive pins are clearly defined. You can't get a response unless you receive your transmitted data via loopback adapter.