# Software to replay a serial signal on a serial port (with accurate timing)?

Tags: serial-port

I was looking for this, but seemingly I cannot find anything relevant - so maybe someone can point out possibilities or software that can do this?

What I need, is to play back, from a file, a signal on a serial port with accurate timing: that means, if the port is set at 115200 baud, 8N1, we have a bit duration of 8.68 μs. So if the file says "TX pin stays low for 2 bit durations (here 17.36 μs), then stays high for 3 bit durations (here 26.04 μs)", then that is what I'd want observed on the TX pin if I measure it on an oscilloscope.

(It would be even better if the serial port can be "bit-banged" with times/durations other than those specified by the current serial port settings, so (say) "TX pin stays low for 5 μs, then stays high for 10 5 μs" can be reproduced somewhat accurately, even if the serial port is set to work at 9600 baud in the OS; in other words, regardless of what the serial port as such is set to in the OS, in terms of *character* transmission baud rate).

That means, that the input should be a file that has some sort of a timing information for playback, such as:

- `.wav` (while it's meant for "analog" playback, one can always set a threshold, and interpret say everything in the range -1.0 to 0.0 as logical LOW, and conversely, everything in the range 0.0 to 1.0 as logical HIGH), or
- [`.vcd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_change_dump) (which has implicit timing information through a "timescale").

So far, I've only found these relevant resources:

- [How can I monitor serial port traffic?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic)

> I run them by using `script -t` so I could replay the whole and trace timing executions.

... but I cannot tell if this means "replay" on the desktop PC as commands, or replay on the serial port as a TX waveform.

And there's this:

- https://hackaday.io/project/162477-serial-port-sdr ( https://github.com/tedyapo/serial-port-sdr )

This project has a script that can accept a `.wav` file and drive a serial port:

```
./serial_sdr_tx.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 -f 631e3 -l -m pdm recorded_codes.wav
```

... however, the github readme notes for this script:

> The `serial_sdr_tx.py` program will generate an amplitude-modulated signal from an audio file.

... and I looked at this script, and it does not look easy to me to remove all the modulation stuff, so that I could reproduce "raw" .wav (with some sort of a threshold) directly.

Is there something like this in Unix/Linux land?

Comment: Serial ports use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter chips, which means they can't be bit-banged in general (it will send a low for the start bit, then 6,7 or 8 bits later it will send a high for a stop bit). What hardware do you have? What are you actually trying to do? A low cost computer such as a raspberry pi has gpio lines you can bit bang, or perhaps a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_Pirate?

Comment: Many thanks @icarus - I your comment: "Serial ports ... can't be bit-banged in general" and related is crucial; I sort of lost track of that. So yeah, the question then only makes sense in respect to hardware with GPIO, like the Raspberry Pi, which could in principle be bit-banged. ...

Comment: ... @icarus - ... To keep it generic: I try to work with some devices, which are controlled by serial controllers; each controller is different in terms of break and bit length in the serial signal, and I can capture their signals with say Saleae Logic. Thus, I'd like to replay these captures, to assist me with device debugging.  Feel free to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it! (with a possible mention of http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html "Wave create" - seems related, though I just found it and haven't tested it yet)

Comment: I think a better answer is possible, so I will leave it open. It is decades since I was bit-banging GPIO lines and I don't know what is current state of the art.