# What are the side effects of using socat to monitor the traffic of a serial port regarding the monitored serial port?

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, socat

**Disclaimer:** Long and detailed problem description + I actually have no idea about `socat`, but ran into a very strange problem. Something similar to a tl;dr at the end.

I am currently trying to connect my computer running Ubuntu 18.04 serially (RS232) to an INS (specifically an Ellipse-D) to send it RTCM correction data so that it can achieve RTK-level GPS accuracy.

For this purpose the BKG Ntrip Client (BNC) is running on my computer, which expects NMEA strings from the INS via the serial interface, sends them via Internet to an NTRIP caster, which in turn sends RTCM correction data back to the NTRIP client, so that the latter can then pass the received correction data to the INS via the serial interface. (Diagram for illustration below.)

Now unfortunately, the INS always indicated that it was not receiving correction data, yet the BNC always received NMEA strings from the INS, as well as RTCM data from the NTRIP caster.
So I decided to try to monitor the traffic on the serial port (in my case /dev/ttyUSB0) to see if the RTCM data was leaving the computer. Thereby, I found the following entry:
[How can I monitor serial port traffic?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic/225904)
So I converted the solution described there, which uses `socat`, ran my system as described above and at the same time opened another terminal in which I executed the following command:

```
socat /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0 \
SYSTEM:'tee in.txt |socat - "PTY,link=/tmp/ttyV0,raw,echo=0,waitslave" |tee out.txt'
```

I expected incoming traffic to end up in `in.txt` and outgoing traffic to end up in `out.txt`. In `in.txt` there were the NMEA strings coming from the INS, but in `out.txt` there was nothing. I was disappointed at first until I noticed that my INS suddenly indicated RTK-level GNSS positions to be estimated, so all of a sudden RTCM correction data landed at the INS. And what surprised me even more, that when I cancelled the `socat` terminal command, that then also the RTK level precision was no longer present, so that no more RTCM data arrived at the INS. I repeated the process a few times and always the same result, so a coincidence can be excluded. (The only interesting thing is that after some time the RTK level precision is not reached any more, but after a restart of the socat command it is immediately reached again).

**tl;dr:** To end this long problem description I ask myself and herewith also you which side effects of the above `socat` command lead to the fact that another program (here BNC) than socat can send data over a serial interface to an external device (here an INS) only if `socat` monitors this interface (here /dev/ttyUSB0), because in my application I don't want to run `socat` always in parallel.

**Diagram:**[image: Picture taken from the BNC manual.]

BNC is running here on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine, and the GNSS rover here is an Ellipse-D INS. The Reference Observations that are to be transmitted serially are the problem, because they only seem to arrive when the above `socat` command is executed at the same time. The NMEA coordinates, on the other hand, always arrive regardless of `socat`.

Comment: There are so many indirections and redirections in the chain, you will need to debug them one at a time. Make sure one program is actually sending data to the serial port, and not somewhere else. Make sure the data is getting to the receiving side. Then make sure the program on the receiving side is actually listening to the serial port. One of them might, for example, by trying to read a TCP/IP port, or a file, instead of the serial port. The `socat` version may have worked better simply because you were very specific telling `socat` what to use.

Comment: I got lost between the acronyms, maybe a diagram would be more helpful. Anyway, serial ports deal with a lot more than passing bytes around, `socat` might be setting (or not setting) a baud rate, for example. Try to check other serial port parameters that might be involved, to see if there is a mismatch between the reader and the device.

Comment: (PART 1): First of all, thank you both for the quick feedback. @C.M. I am very sure that data, and in fact in the correct format (NMEA) arrive at my computer in the BNC program, since both the internal log from the BNC suggests this and also socat verifies this, because the same data are in in.txt after execution of the socat command. However, unfortunately I can not monitor whether data arrives at the other side, i.e. at the INS, because the firmware of the INS does not allow this...

Comment: (PART 2): ...This was also the reason to use socat in the first place, as I had promised myself that by executing the command the data going from the computer to the INS via the serial port would be logged in out.txt, which unfortunately was not the case, but led to the very strange result that the INS received data all of a sudden. Maybe you can suggest me an alternative way how to monitor the traffic otherwise.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I will now add an improvised diagram to the question, as well as document the changes to the serial port parameters triggered by socat.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I meanwhile compared the `stty` settings of `/dev/ttyUSB0` before and after running the `socat` command. The difference was this line:
Before `socat`: `rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 0; time = 1;`
After `socat`: `rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;`
I don't think that's the reason, because I also tried to manually set it that way myself, and unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: You are using `stty -a`, right? Those two values deal with buffering. Instead of running `socat` try to run `stty raw < /dev/ttyUSB0`, does it work?

Comment: Can you use something else, maybe on another redirected port, to check for data arrival? Even possibly another computer if needed, to use to compare and contrast the settings, data sent vs rcvd, and so on. I.E., try to narrow down and isolate _where_ the problem is, and the solution may become obvious or at least someone with similar issues may know a solution, I am nearly useless to help with modern serial comm as I have not used serial since the 90's/early 2K's... but the process of diagnosing and troubleshooting has not changed much.